# Host behavior with mask +1 and -1

Tags: ipv4, ip, layer3, network

Let's suppose I have a configuration:

```
host: 192.168.1.145/25
gateway: 192.168.1.129
network: 192.168.1.128/25
broadcast: 192.168.1.255
```

What happens if I add +1 bit and remove -1 bit to the mask?

1) /26

```
network: 192.168.1.128/26
broadcast: 192.168.1.191
```

Does it affect the host IP?

2) /24

```
network: 192.168.1.0/24
broadcast: 192.168.1.255
```

Does it affect the host IP?

So with this example I don't see any difference. But maybe I make something wrong? How should such type of example be done?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

All your assumptions are correct. Subnet mask determines subnet length. So in cases you described length of network changes, but host remains inside of the network. The difference is .145 will not need routing entry (except connected 192.168.1 one) in order to reach, say, .200 with /24 and /25 mask, but it will need route in order to reach the same .200 host with /26 mask. And similarly it'll reach .1 without routing entry with /24 mask, but not with /25 and /26.